# Populate a field based on a field in another object

Tags: custom-field

Object1.fieldA - picklist, user enters the value according to the account info. In cases of leads or opportunity, account is empty and so this field.

Object2.fieldA - text formula field, defined by: TEXT( Object1.fieldA ).

I always have an Object2 (leads, opportunity, account). If Object1.fieldA is empty - I want to be able to set fieldA via object2. Currently I can't since it's a formula field.

Actually, I'd like to see the same field, both on object1 and on object2, meaning that object2.fieldA is actually object1.fieldA in disguise.

How can I do that?

And another question: if I want to change a custom field (name, type) how can I know where this field is being referred to (and enter the changes there as well)?

Thanks

Comment: answer for your second question would be http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98419/find-the-field-reference-while-before-delete-the-record/98420#98420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the first Input Field IS NOT a formula field and your formula is a WFR field update...

Your formula to set the value of the field would look like this:

Assuming your field is named INPUTFIELD__c

```
IF( 
  AND(
    NOT(
       ISBLANK(INPUTFIELD__c)
    ),
    ISBLANK(TEXT( Account.Terriroty__c ))
  ),
    INPUTFIELD__c,
  TEXT( Account.Terriroty__c )
)
```

Basically it says that if the Input field is not blank AND the Account.Territory field IS blank then keep the data entered in the input field, otherwise set it to the value of the Account.territory

If my assumption is not correct, please specify in more detail about the fields and what you want to do as it is a bit unclear. If the field is a formula field type then you cannot allow and data entry. You will have to change to a string field and use a WFR to update it.

Comment: Eric, thanks for taking the time to answer, I'm afraid I've not explained myself clearly. I've edited my question, hope now it's clearer. Would appreciate you response.

Comment: @RachelS. - You say **Actually, I'd like to see the same field, both on object1 and on object2, meaning that object2.fieldA is actually object1.fieldA in disguise** - That is what you are doing by the formula. So I am still confused. Change the field on object 2 to be a text field and set it using a WFR if it is not blank (user entered) - Maybe thats what you meant. If so you can still use my answer to do that (slight modification putting in proper field names)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to make a formula also be a text-entry field.  You'll likely need to change the contact.region field to be a text field, and then create a workflow rule that evaluates changes to the Contact, and updates the field if the account.territory__c isn't blank, and/or if the contact.region field is blank.  The real trick will be determining how/when the WFR should fire.  And if it is tied to the account changing, it's even more of a challenge, but doable.

Comment: Hi Homer, please read my edited question. I hope it's easier to understand.