# Find the field reference before delete the record

Tags: fields, field-update

If I want to change a custom field (name, type) how can I know where this field is being referred to (and enter the changes there as well)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about the field is referred at least once from somewhere you can directly try to attempt to delete the field and it will give you an error with the places that the field is referred from.

Second option is you can checkout your entire projects metadata (eg:- using Force.com IDE or mavensmate) and search for the field reference with the field API name.